# How to make the Flask app working in real time with two pages one page for data entry and another for display concurrently?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a flask app to enter data by a person through a page and display through another page to all. This is done with following as app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        date = request.form.get('date')
        return redirect(url_for('booking', date=date))
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/display')
def booking():
    date = request.args.get('date', None)
    return render_template('display.html', date=date)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

with index.html:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h3>Home page</h3>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <label for="date">Date: </label>
      <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

with display.html:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h3>Date display</h3>
    <p>
      Seleted date: {{ date }}
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now what happens is upon selecting a date in index.html, upon submitting, users are taken to display.html with date value in url and displayed.
But what I want is the display page should independently display the data whatever is entered through index.html  dynamically. My app requires data entry will be done by one person and display will be seen by rest all in real time.
Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. You're going to need to arrange a way for the two views of your application to communicate -- which means you're going to need to learn some javascript, at least.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @larsks. I am very poor in that...looking for some guidance so that two pages will work concurrently with update behind.

Comment: It seems that you don't need a bidirectionale communications. Maybe server sent events (flask-sse) could be considered, one page sending, another listening!? See also http://html5doctor.com/server-sent-events/ or https://maxhalford.github.io/blog/flask-sse-no-deps/